# How to sort table with the same type data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have this code table:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sortner" data-target="type">Sort By Type</button>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="sortner" data-status="type">
            <td>Shoes<td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="sortner" data-status="type2">
            <td>Gloves<td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="sortner" data-status="type">
            <td>Shock<td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="sortner" data-status="type2">
            <td>Pad<td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to sorting a `<tr>` with the same data-status using jQuery? 
I'm looking to this jQuery function but I don't know how to sorting:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-sortner').on('click', function () {
        var $target = $(this).data('target');
        var $type_row = $('tr.sortner').data('status');

        if ($target == $type_row) {
            //do sortof the table with the same type row
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the expected o/p ?

Comment: have you tried googling ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

Comment: i've googling and look other similiar problem but didn't found sortner with the same type that i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

think you want a sort function.

```
 data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return (a.status > b.status) ? 1 : ((b.status > a.status) ? -1 : 0)
        })
```

here is a fiddle of your data where you can sort by status, or name.

https://jsfiddle.net/5mshnLj2/

Comment: bless you.. and thank you very much this is what i really need it.